# serverSocket not listening

Tags: java, networking, serversocket

serverSocket not listening on port of localhost, i tried several ports. even without timeout line it is not working. please suggest any modifications in this code.

```
public class server1 extends JApplet implements Serializable{

static JApplet japplet = new JApplet();
private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private static Socket clientSocket = null;
private static final int maxClientsCount = 5;
private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

public void init() {
    tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    setup_applet();
    setup_layout();
    run();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(60000);

    while (true) {
        screen.init_Screen();
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                if (threads[i] == null) {
                    (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads))
                            .start();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == maxClientsCount) {
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}

class clientThread extends Thread implements Serializable {

private String clientName = null;
private PrintStream os = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
private final clientThread[] threads;
private int maxClientsCount;

public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
}

public void run() {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

    try {
        os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {
            String msg = "server:apl";
            synchronized (this) {
                for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
                        os.println(msg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            synchronized (this) {
                for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
                            && threads[i].clientName != null) {
                        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                        if(image != null) {
                            soms1.screen.paint(image.getGraphics());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("failed to get");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            os.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

I even checked firewall and if the ports are not been used by another process.
any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't work. `serverSocket.accept();` will wait for a new connection. Your code never gets to the line where you start a new client thread unless you actually connect to the server socket. I suggest you add the code for the client socket also

Answer (score 0):

This comes with no surprise. The application you have developed is a Java applet. Which means that the usual execution container it will run in is a web-browser. Of course the Java browser plugin has to pose security restrictions on applets running in a users browser. Otherwise applets would be a perfect way to ship malicious code to users.

The protection mechanism is called sandboxing. This poses many restrictions, the only restriction important in your context is, that an applet is only allowed to open network connections to the host and port they came from. This means they can make HTTP calls to the server they were loaded from. For details see the documentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

However, you can sign your applet as explained here, to get rid of these restrictions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html
For signed applets an existing manifest file is parsed.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html

Long answer short: Properly sign your applet and you should be good to go.

Comment: is there any way i can do socket transfer without signing? or can i use other technique instead of applet? in above code i intend to generate graphic image in applet and transfer it to server for saving purpose.

Comment: Of course you could always make a complete technology switch. Implement the drawing functionality in HTML5, JavaScript and draw to a canvas. You can always post the current content of a canvas via HTTP. However, this would be a completely different question.